# Why do we use null geodesics?

Tags: general-relativity, geodesics

Why do we use the null geodesic equation not only for the photon but for all GR?

I thought the null geodesic was only it to the photon, How do these things intertwine?

Null geodesic equation

And not null

Comment: Photons follow null geodesics, massive particles do not.  Can you clarify your question?

Comment: When we describe the world line of a particle, don't we use the null geodesic equation?

Comment: And to describe orbits for example in the scharwzschild metric we use null geodesics

Comment: So much so that the null geodesic equation is said to be the geodesic equation

Comment: No, we don't.  We use the geodesic equation, solutions to which may be null, lightlike, or spacelike.  If you provide a null (/spacelike/timelike) initial condition, then the worldline will remain null (/spacelike/timelike), but that's separate from the equation itself.

Comment: More why most of the time if I look I find the null equation

Comment: Maybe it would be better to write down what you think the "null geodesic equation" is, and how that is different from the equation for a generic geodesic.

Comment: Convention, or not?

Comment: I'll put a picture in the question waiting for me

Comment: The non-null would be that it is=1/2F² and has some derivative ai I n wrote everything because I think that only this is already to understand

Comment: That's just the geodesic equation.  The null/spacellike/timelike condition needs to be placed on the vector independently of satisfying the geodesic equation.  You can prove that the spacellike/timelike nature of a curve cannot change along a geodesic.

Comment: The one I quoted where F=ds²/dτ² is for when then

Comment: I don't understand which question you're asking about, but the equation in the image is the one satisfied by any geodesic, whether timelike, spacelike, or null.  Which type of geodesic you're describing is an initial condition of the system.

Comment: I was going to send the image of the geodesic that I'm talking about more But exceeds 2 mb so did not give, shit

Comment: But if it's the initial condition of the equation i was thinking then I understood

Comment: I I'il  try to use an app to change the size i'll be right back and text if I can

Comment: I was able to look at it to see if you recognize and recognize the difference between the two

Comment: Hi Miles. Please do not post formulae as images, but use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/143136) instead.

Comment: I'm going to erase right

Answer (score 2):

Your question is based on a false premise.  The equation

$$ \frac{d^2x^\mu}{ds^2} + \Gamma^\mu_{ \ \ \alpha\beta} \frac{dx^\alpha}{ds} \frac{dx^\beta}{ds} = 0$$

is solved by **any** geodesic, whether it be null, spacelike, or timelike.  If you want a null geodesic, you need to add the additional condition that $g_{\mu\nu} \frac{dx^\alpha}{ds}\frac{dx^\beta}{ds} = 0$, but this is a condition above and beyond the geodesic equation.

Comment: There's an equation that seemed to be more general than this, but I can't send a picture because it exceeds 2 mb and it's confusing me

Comment: @MilesUpshur I don't know what to tell you.  What I've written in my answer is the geodesic equation.  If you had something on the right hand side, then you weren't solving the geodesic equation.  That's what happens when a particle is under the influence of a force, like you'd have from an electromagnetic field or something.  But those aren't geodesics.

Comment: Oh I understand

Answer (score 0):

Null geodesic is the path followed only by massless particles where in cartesian coord. line element

$$ds^2 = - c^2 dt^2 + dx^2 +dy^2+dz^2 = 0$$

Null geodesic implies with an affine parameter $\lambda$

$$g_{\mu \nu}U^{\mu}U^{\nu}= \Big(\frac{ds}{d \lambda}\Big)^2 = 0$$

So

$$\Gamma^{\mu}_{\alpha \beta} \frac{d x^{\alpha}}{d \lambda} \frac{d x^{\beta}}{d \lambda} = 0$$

Comment: I'll try to use an app to change the size of the image if I get 
i  send message

Comment: Tey using online apps to reduce its size